# Loadrunner Controller to an Amazon EC2 Linux Server

Tags: loadrunner

How to pass Loadrunner Controller credentials to an Amazon EC2 Linux Server. I am trying to monitor an Amazon EC2 Linux server. When I 'Add Measurements using the controller, the contoller is prompting for the server name but is not asking for the server credentials. When I run the loadrunner test I am getting an RPC client error. RSTATD is running in EC2. I have verified this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use RSTATD.   This has not been the recommended model for monitoring of 'nix environments since the inclusion of SiteScope with every LoadRunner license with LoadRunner version 8.0

Use SiteScope and the SSH connectivity to the Load Generator.   You will be prompted for credentials.   You will have challenges because of the virtualized nature of all machines in EC2.  You are at the whim of whatever the Hypervisor reports to the OS as to what level of resource is being used.   The most accurate measurements will be from the Hypervisor itself, which unfortunately only Amazon has access to in their environment